# C/C++ extern "C" Variable compilation Macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

How do I test to see if I am linking in C++ or C using macros?
Say I have code that should link as C in a C++ file, I would use `extern "C"{//code here}`which would make my code in a link as C . How would I set up my `name.c` file to work for both C and C++. Something like...

```
#ifdef C++//or other macro
extern "C"{
#endif

#ifdef C++
}
#endif
```

What is the proper macro to replace the "C++" I have above, and will it be cross platform? or how can I set it up to be cross platform?

Also, What is the significance of having to do the `extern "C"{}` for C code in a C++ file?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus`

Comment: (also, if you have **two** questions, then post two separate questions. The answer to your second question is not only easily googleable [well, so is the first one], but it's quite lengthy.)

Comment: @user3477950 I will be sure to do that next time if I have a multi part question.

Comment: @user3477950 the answer is actually very short. *There is no such thing as C code in a C++ file*.

Comment: @n.m. Well, yeah, too bad a lot of people are trying to treat C as if it was a subset of C++... :'(

Comment: @n.m. When I said "C code in a C++ file" I meant code that should be linked as C rather than C++. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: @n.m. Yes there in theory is no such thing as C code in a C++ file but I would argue that there is such a things a "C compatible" code in a C++ file, meaning code from a .cpp file that if put into a .c file would compile and link without modification. Much like C++ being am extension of the C language allowing code written for a C compiler to function without major modification in a C++ environment just in reverse.

Comment: Why the heck is this voted down? It's a perfectly reasonable question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"What is the proper macro to replace the "C++""*

It's `#ifdef __cplusplus`

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

//.....

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

> For *"...What is the significance of having to do....?"*

Read : [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern “C”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041866/1870232)

Comment: @user3477950 **Its** _"What is the proper macro to replace the "C++""_

Comment: That would be "It's", with an apostrophe inserted at position 2.